# Moving segments colliding

Tags: vector-spaces, computer-science, collision-detection

I need to check if the edges of two triangles will collide. I do an edge-edge check for each pair. One segment is stationary, while the other moves with constant velocity. The segments are not deformable( the position of the moving points will only change due to the velocity ).

I've tried doing some vector math myself, but had no luck. I found out how to check if two segments intersect and where, but they have to be coplanar, so I still need to know the exact moment along the velocity when they will get coplanar, and if that moment actually exists. If not, obviously, no collision happened.

Comment: How do you check if two coplanar segments intersect?

Comment: If you know they are coplanar, you can use what is described here: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/62814.html       If a is between [0,1], you have an intersection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the right answer myself and decided to share it with the community. Maybe someone else will encounter this problem too.

By the way: Sorry, draks ..., but I didn't see your comment until today. Look at this picture, the second case: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP29I.png

Okay, so here it goes:

If you have segments A1B1 and A2B2, the first immobile and the second moving with linear velocity, you can actually project A2B2 on the colliding plane: The segment A1P will be its projection, where P = A1 + ( A2 - B2 ). You will then get the plane normal by crossing A1B1 and A1P. If you know the plane coordinates, you can then calculate when, along the velocity, will A2B2 intersect that plane. Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 1):

You can [determining whether a point is inside a triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinates_%28mathematics%29#Determining_whether_a_point_is_inside_a_triangle) by using barycentric coordinates $\lambda_i$: Point $\mathbf{r}$ lies inside the triangle if and only if $0 < \lambda_i < 1 \;\forall\; i \text{ in } 1,2,3$.

Choose the first triangle to be fixed and check whether any vertex of the other lies inside the fixed one.

Comment: I know how to check if a point lies inside a triangle, and, besides, I didn't ask that. Please read my question again.

Comment: Even so it's a helpful answer!

Comment: It does not answer the question, so it's useless. It is completely off-topic.

Comment: @Lighthink: When you want to know whether two triangles or their edges collide, doesn't it suffice to know that one vertex of one triangle hits the border of the other?

Comment: No. Actually, I thought that too, but let's consider two pieces of paper, both of them standing vertically, one above the other, the above one falling in a straight line. Their centers have the same x and z coordinates( assuming y is height ), but their y-axis rotation is different. Imagine them falling. Do any point in one piece of paper touch the other piece of paper? No. But their edges collide.

Comment: hmm, I don't get it, can you draw a picture?